# Seaborn is missing a bin of histogram. Is this a bug of seaborn, or my misusing?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

This is a piece of code plotting a histogram with matplotlib

```
rng = np.random.RandomState(10)
a = rng.normal(size=10000)
# set width as {0.01, 0.02, 0.03}
_ = plt.hist(a, bins=9)
```

[image]

This is a piece of code plotting the same histogram with seaborn

```
sns.distplot(a, norm_hist=False, kde=False, bins=9, hist_kws={"alpha": 1})
```

When I add some settings to make the plot nicer:

```
sns.set(style='whitegrid', palette="deep", font_scale=1.1, rc={"figure.figsize": [8, 5]})
sns.distplot(a, norm_hist=False, kde=False, bins=9, hist_kws={"alpha": 1})
```

the right most bin is gone!

[image]

Is this a bug of seaborn, or my misusing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use also this parameter `'linewidth':0.1` in `hist_kws`:

```
sns.distplot(a, norm_hist=False, kde=False, bins=9, hist_kws={"alpha": 1, 'linewidth':0.1})
```

[image]

Comment: You can try with `0.3`, but the bigger the value, less you will see the bin